# How to configure JsonProperty Required.Always to work with not nullable value types

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have faced the problem with Newtonsoft.Json - v10.0.0 (.Net Framework V4.6.2)

**Code example**

```
public class AnyClass
{
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public int AnyInt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public DateTime? NullableTimestamp { get; set; }
}
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Handle(AnyClass anyInstance)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
}
```

**Expected behavior**

The exception will throw for the "AnyClass" property that does not present in JSON including those that can not be null.

**Actual behavior**

The exception trows for NullableTimestamp only as it can be null

**The question**
What I did wrong or it is just a bug?

Comment: *I have faced the problem with Newtonsoft.Json - v4.0.30319* - are you sure this is the version you are using?  [4.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.0.3) is very old, from Nov 3, 2014.  If this is the version you are using, is there any chance you could upgrade, or at least test with a up-to-date version to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: There is no relation to example 
I will remove it

Comment: I will try to update to the latest version, just to check this case.

Comment: The old version was 10.0.0
Update Newtonsoft.Json to 12.0.3 (latest stable) didn't help